# ZIP Code suffix results only

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need help creating a query that will result with just the zip code suffix. Some have the 4 digit extension and others don't....I just need the suffix of the ones that do and not the whole zip code.

example: 66227-4567 - I am trying to get "4567"

I've unsuccessfully tried;

- case statements
- count - not sure why but figured I'd give it a try
- right(zipcode,4) - but this does not account for zip codes
  that don't have the suffix

I am now out of ideas and need some help

Comment: `case when charindex('-', col) > 0 then right(col, 4) else '' end`

Comment: You are on the right track with `RIGHT(ZIPCODE,4)`.  Interrogate the length of the ZIPCODE, if it's greater than 6 characters (this will acount for situations where the zip could be '12345-'), then apply the `RIGHT` function.  As a fun-fact, those 4 digits at the end are culled the 'Plus 4' portion of the zipcode.

Comment: very cool! thanks very much Kris

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
declare @Tab Table ( Col nvarchar(100)) 

Insert into @Tab values ('66227-4567')
Insert into @Tab values ('66227-45')
Insert into @Tab values ('66227-4')
Insert into @Tab values ('66227-')
Insert into @Tab values ('66227')
Insert into @Tab values ('66227-456712345')
Insert into @Tab values ('66227-  ')
Insert into @Tab values ('')

Select NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Col, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', Col),0)+1, LEN(Col)))),'') from @Tab
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest I can think of that I think would work is

```
SELECT ZipCode FROM MyTable 
  WHERE ZipCode LIKE '%-____'
```